# Not able to find css stylesheets or images - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I'm new to web development but have some experience with C#, so I'm trying my luck with ASP.NET. 
I was able to create the base app and so on, however now I want to use my own CSS stylesheet.

I tried using the exact syntax that the base app uses:

```
<head runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
         <title>@ViewData["Title"] - SmtteProject</title>

         <environment include="Development">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
         </environment>
         <environment exclude="Development">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                   asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                   asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute"
                   crossorigin="anonymous"
                   integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"/>

         </environment>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/test.css"/>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
     </head>
```

Where the test.css is the stylesheet I want to use. It is in the exact same directory as site.css, however I get this error in the console on the page:

GET http://localhost:5000/css/test.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I tried using `runat="server"` in both the head and in the link, as I saw quite a few answers online with this solution. However, that did not do the trick either.

I tried displaying an image that was in an images directory in the exact same way, but encountered the same issue.

Any help welcome.

Comment: can you show your directory structure , most probably css is not at right place.

Comment: Remove the cache of this site or on developer panel of the browser disable cache. I think you will not have the 'Site.css' also.

Comment: Sure @paritosh . Here is my directory: [http://prntscr.com/n8mq5e](http://prntscr.com/n8mq5e)

Comment: Is there any webconfig file available?

Comment: There is not. At least not as far as I can tell. Should I add one?

Comment: Is work with local machine?

Comment: @Farzin Kanzi I disabled the browser cache, but It still finds 'Site.ccs' and does not find 'test.ccs'

Comment: @MuhammadOvais Yes it is

Comment: @paritosh Should I change my directory setup?

Comment: @Mars1234 It's **C**ascading **S**tyle **S**heets, or *CSS*. Not *CCS*.

Comment: @DanielMann Oh my bad. That was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **C**ascading **S**tyle **S**heets, or *CSS*. Not *CCS*. I think that this naming confusion is the root of your problem.

Your file is named `test.ccs`. It should be named `test.css`, per the HTML snippet you provided.

Comment: Yeah that was a stupid mistake. Thanks for the help though.